# autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset() Why does my Z values swing from 0 to 1g in static condition?

Tags: accelerometer, code-review, 101, genuino

I tried to implement the [`autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieIMUautoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset) function, through the code below on Arduino Genuino 101.

In a static test, without any stress or noise, I read the three axis value.

When I see the data on the serial monitor or on my file created with processing, the Z acceleration values changes from 1~0,99 to 0,00 g.

[image]

I think there is an error in my code.

```cpp
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "CurieIMU.h"

float sensorVals[] = {0,0,0}; 

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600); 
    while (!Serial);    

    Serial.println("Inizializzazione del device...");
    CurieIMU.begin();

    CurieIMU.setAccelerometerRange(2);
    CurieIMU.autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset(X_AXIS,0);
    CurieIMU.autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset(Y_AXIS,0);
    CurieIMU.autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset(Z_AXIS,1);
}

void loop() {

    sensorVals[0] = CurieIMU.readAccelerometerScaled(0);
    sensorVals[1] = CurieIMU.readAccelerometerScaled(1);
    sensorVals[2] = CurieIMU.readAccelerometerScaled(2);

    Serial.print(sensorVals[0]); 
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(sensorVals[1]);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(sensorVals[2]);
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add CurieIMU.autoCalibrateGyroOffset(); right after CurieIMU.begin(); ?

Comment: Do you know you have Z oriented as expected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this old abandoned question as information to make it answerable has never been provided.  The obvious way to debug this is to print out both the raw and calibrated values.  That would show if it is a reading error, or the more likely case of the calibration "calibrating out" gravity.

Comment: If it is calibrating out gravity, why does it flip between values? I would be interested to see it calibrated, then tipped slightly in X/Y to see if the rows with "Z: 0" also have X/Y: 0 (they shouldnt), and if they do, then it's likely an issue with the sensor or reading too quickly from the sensor, or similar. I just dont see how calibrating out the Z would flip between 0 and 1 as per sample

Comment: @SDsolar because is a specific function of CURIE IMU library compatible only with Arduino and Genuino 101 only

Comment: @ChrisStratton the problem is related in my opinion to the Official Library function not with the sensor reading, because without applying the calibration function  in the same condition and without perturbations the sensors reading doesn't have any swinging values

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't jumping up and down while this is happening then it could be:

- A loose wire
- A dodgy power supply
- A bad earth connection
- A fault sensor
- A weird magnetic field/flux thing

Check you wiring, make sure all the connections are secure, etc.  I bet you have done that already.

I have no idea how to check a power supply, but if you have a different one you could switch that in.  Also look into smoothing the power supply with decoupling capacitors (?)

A bad earth, all sorts of weird [stuff] happens when you haven't earthed things properly.  Different power supplies need to share earths, but I suspect that doesn't apply here.

A faulty sensor - again, unless you have a duplicate you might not know.

Weird flux.  I think the sensor is a magnetic sensor and so it could be the natural eddies and flows of magnetic flux have conspired against you.  Move the sensor away from power supplies, electrical things and specifically anything you are hacking.  Also rotate the sensor through 90 degrees and see if it still happens (With RF it will polarise the fields in a different way, and school was a long time ago and I can't remember if that works with magnetic fields too)

Comment: If i don't use the autoCalibrateAccelerometerOffset(), and i get the raw data  the values are not calibrated but stable, so i think i can exclude: Fault sensor, Power Supply, Loose Wire, Faulty Sensor, a weird magnetic field :) Thanks

Comment: An accelerometer has nothing to do with magnetic fields, unless the fields are strong enough to physically move the device.